# Camel | When does the RouteBuilder execute on updated files?

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I set up a basic Route:

```java
RouteBuilder route = new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("file:OrderSystem?fileName=orders.txt&noop=true")
                        .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
                        .process(OrderFactory)
                        .to("jms:queue:inqueue");
           }
};
```

When I run `ctxt.start()` with the added route, the data from the file is immediately in my ActiveMQ Queue. I have a `Thread.sleep(999999)` afterwards, to make sure Camel stays alive, but even so my `orders.txt` file is updated with new data, nothing is added to the queue anymore. How can I route updated data in the file to my queue? What do I need to execute to request the data or observe changes?

(And how do I delete the data within the file using camel, but not the file itself?)

Thank you for any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Camel File Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html), the description of parameter `noop`is

> If true, the file is not moved or deleted in any way. This option is
> good for readonly data, or for ETL type requirements. **If noop=true,
> Camel will set idempotent=true as well, to avoid consuming the same
> files over and over again**.

Actually, your route is scanning the folder every 500 ms (default value of delay) and look for a file with name `orders.txt`. BUT the default `idempotent` setup (turn on by `noop`) stop you from pick-up the "same" file.

To achieve you goal, you need to adjust the parameter `idempotentKey` to tell Camel how to determine a file is being processed or not (default setting is file path). e.g. Use both file name and size `idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}`